# How do I import my PPA signing keys from a host into a virtual machine?

Tags: command-line, application-development, ppa, gnupg

Please, give me some help:
How can I export PGP keys I used for registration on PPA and then import in virtual machine's Ubuntu?
Please, help me.

Comment: You can View [this](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) and also installing **seahorse** would be helpful. Also found a [Adding a Launchpad PPA's key to Ubuntu video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUZOQsNo_ws&feature=related)

Comment: And the official [GPG wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GnuPrivacyGuardHowto#Backing%20up%20and%20restoring%20your%20key%20pair) and/or [here](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-import-export-gpg-key-pair).

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you can copy-and-paste between the host and the virtual machine guest; it's easier than setting up sharing between the two, and more secure than emailing your private key to yourself, leaving key files lying around, etc.

1. **Host AND VM:** Open a terminal, and `sudo apt-get install xclip` (a small tool to copy and paste to the clipboard from the command-line)
2. **Host:** Type `gpg --list-keys` and select the 8-letter "pub" key you used for PPA signing, e.g. if the output is `pub   2048D/ABCD0123 2012-05-02`, you want `ABCD0123`.
3. **Host:** Type `gpg -a --export ABCD0123 | xclip`
4. **VM:** Type `xclip -o | gpg --import`, to add your public key.
5. **Host:** Type `gpg -a --export-secret-key ABCD0123 | xclip`
6. **VM:** Type `xclip -o | gpg --allow-secret-key-import`, to add your private key.

That's it!